# How to exit a Docker Remote API Exec Stream?

Tags: go, docker

When I get a stream from Docker Remote API like this:

```
// Exec exec command
func (d *Docker) ExecStart(host, id string) (net.Conn) {
    config := map[string]interface{}{
        "Detach": false,
        "Tty":    true,
    }

    buf, _ := json.Marshal(config)

    conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", host)
    conn.Write([]byte("POST /exec/" + id + "/start HTTP/1.1\r\n"))
    conn.Write([]byte("Host:\r\n"))
    conn.Write([]byte("Connection: Upgrade\r\n"))
    conn.Write([]byte("Content-Type: application/json\r\n"))
    conn.Write([]byte("Upgrade: tcp\r\n"))
    conn.Write([]byte("Content-Length: " + fmt.Sprintf("%d", len(buf)) + "\r\n"))
    conn.Write([]byte("\r\n"))
    conn.Write(buf)
    return conn
}
```

After that, I disconnect the conn, but when I use `curl /exec/id/json` to get the status of result, the sh still running. So I want to know the best way to close the sh, even in `vi` mode. thx :)